# How to change storage engines in mySQL?

Tags: mysql

I tried to change the storage engine from 'MyISAM' to 'CSV'. But it failed as it mentioned CSV does not support AUTO_INCREMENT. Any solution to solve this?

Comment: Don't use `CSV` if you want auto_increment.

Comment: Remove your AUTO_INCREMENT indexing system before changing the engine, if that is what you want.

Comment: Will try that, thanks. Aside from that, my dropbox files are currently synced to mySQL and in MyISAM.  Is it possible to convert those dropbox files to csv?